# One-body General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

Does it make sense to talk in General Relativity about only 1 body ? Can you have a universe in which there is only one body and that body is producing a gravitational field ? I'm asking this because I am thinking that gravitation without a second body to test the existence of gravitation doesn't make sense, so a universe with only one body cannot exist.

If you are not sure what 1 body might mean, you can consider a black-hole. Can there be a universe with only 1 black-hole and nothing else ?

Comment: A physical theory assumes that there are suitable technical ways of measuring the quantities that it postulates. In case of general relativity that would be the existence of small test masses which can be used to map out the geometry without changing it. One of the problems with the search for a quantum theory of gravity is, indeed, that it's not clear how one would actually define the necessary physical quantities operationally, since there don't seem to be suitable "test bodies" to bridge the gap from the macroscopic world to the scale on which quantum gravity, if it exists, would live.

Comment: "so a universe with only one body cannot exist" Perhaps it does exist,but unless that body is YOU,you would never know. I think you are wasting your time in meaningless thoughts. Every physics theory starts by studying a single source in isolation.Obviously this is an idealized model of a real source sufficiently distant/isolated from anything else. Continues....

Answer (score 2):

It's important to be clear that general relativity is a mathematical model intended to predict the results of experiments. Different physicists will have different views about how closely GR corresponds to whatever *reality* means, but when asking questions about it you need to remember that it is just a model.

Now, you ask:

> Does it make sense to talk in General Relativity about only 1 body ? Can you have a universe in which there is only one body and that body is producing a gravitational field ?

And if you're asking about general relativity then the answer is yes it does make sense, because this is exactly what the Schwarzschild metric is. It describes a point mass that exists in a spacetime containing no other masses. Although we tend to talk about the Schwarzschild metric as describing a black hole, it actually describes an entire infinite and static universe.

Answer (score 0):

Just the principle of a universe consisting of only 1 black hole doesn't make sense. You will quickly end up with more than 1 body via Hawking radiation. The 1 body problem may help one in understanding self energy contributions of general relativity, but not anything that would probably be observable. However, I have not looked deeply into the case of the 1 body gravitational problem myself. It is probably trivial and also as I stated above, unrealistic.

Comment: "However, I have not looked deeply into the case of the 1 body gravitational problem myself." Google *Schwaraschild metric*...

Comment: Yes, I am fully aware of the Schwarzschild metric..

Answer (score 0):

**Does it make sense to talk in General Relativity about only 1 body?**

Yes. But note that this body is a body in space. The energy tied up in the matter of a star "conditions" the surrounding space, altering its metrical properties. You can see Einstein talking about this sort of thing [here](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol7-trans/192?highlightText=%22neither%20homogeneous%22):

*"According to this theory the metrical qualities of the continuum of space-time differ in the environment of different points of space-time, and are partly conditioned by the matter existing outside of the territory under consideration. This space-time variability of the reciprocal relations of the standards of space and time, or, perhaps, the recognition of the fact that 'empty space' in its physical relation is neither homogeneous nor isotropic, compelling us to describe its state by ten functions (the gravitation potentials g$_{\mu\nu}$), has, I think, finally disposed of the view that space is physically empty."*

Then like John Rennie said, we talk about things like the Schwarzschild metric, then we talk about curved spacetime and worldlines etc.

**Can you have a universe in which there is only one body and that body is producing a gravitational field?**

Yes, but with the proviso that space is something like *a gin-clear ghostly elastic body in which the other body sits*. People think of space as nothing, but Einstein didn't. He thought of it as a something.

**If you are not sure what 1 body might mean, you can consider a black-hole. Can there be a universe with only 1 black-hole and nothing else?**

I think the answer is yes. If you think about big-bang cosmology, the very early universe was in some respects akin to a black hole. There's [plenty of articles about this sort of thing](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=big+bang+black+hole). But note that the *the whole of space* was like a black hole. There was no space around it, and so no gravitational field around it. Also note that [the FLRW metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric#General_metric) *"starts with the assumption of homogeneity and isotropy of space"*, and that Einstein described a gravitational field as space that was *"neither homogeneous nor isotropic"*. There's no gravitational field around this thing, and no overall gravitational field within it either. So gravity doesn't interfere with the expansion of the early universe, even though the density is high.